# .gitignore - difficulty with folder exclusion being ignored

Tags: git

I am trying to ignore a folder from my git pushes using a .gitignore file... and it works for a lot of the things defined in it, but one particular inclusion doesn't seem to be respected.

```
#Others
assets/
```

And then in my folder structure...

```
./
../src
.../web
...../wwwroot
......../assets
```

but when I go to do a push, it still tries to include the assets folder. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Have you ever added the assets folder to Git before?

Comment: how did you add this directory?  I would have expected to see the full path in the .gitignore file, eg  src/web/wwwroot/assets/

Comment: No, I've never added it to git before. Visual Studio created it after a `gulpfile.js` task ran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gitignore` will only ignore *untracked* files, which means that if the directory was already commited (either intentionally or by accident) when you added it to the `.gitignore` file, then you have to remove it before Git will ignore it properly.

If this is the case, then you can run `git rm -r --cached file-or-directory`. (This only "untracks" the file from Git, but doesn't delete it.) If you then run `git status`, it should show up as "deleted" but not as "untracked". (If it shows up under untracked, then the file isn't ignored by Git). Then you can commit the changes and Git should now ignore the directory.

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. Perfect! Thank you so much, it was driving me nuts!