# .gitignore being ignored despite `rm --cached`?

Tags: git, gitignore

works-as-designed

Similar:
[35735862/gitignore-difficulty-with-folder-exclusion-being-ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735862/gitignore-difficulty-with-folder-exclusion-being-ignored)

### Goal:

I'd like `git add .` to not result in my file being tracked.

### Build info: ##`

git version 2.24.1.windows.2` using Windows PowerShell on Windows 10.

### First attempt: mysf.txt

My file is `mysf.txt` (my_secret_file).

`./gitignore` contains: `mysf.txt`, but I've also tried absolute paths and `.\mysf.txt` to no effect.

`git add . > git status` reports that mysf.txt being tracked.

`git rm --cached mysf.txt > git commit > git status` reports that the file is "untracked".

### Second Attempt: secret_file.txt

So, I deleted mysf.txt and made a new file called `secret_file.txt`.

Now, I've ensured that the text, `secret_file.txt`, is added to `.gitignore` **before** doing the following:

```
git add .
git echo "this file is to be ignored." > secret_file.txt
git commit
git status
```

secret_file.txt is not tracked.  Now, I type `git add .` and secret_file.txt is tracked!

Comment: Did you mean to add before creating the secret file?

Comment: Yes.  I did that intentionally because I was told that adding files prior to creating .gitignore might be the source of the problem.  On further investigation, it doesn't matter when you add files as long as you remove them with `git rm --cached <filename>`.

Comment: The first is "works as designed".

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

**Change the encoding of .gitignore to utf-8.**

This can be accomplished in a number of ways.  Notepad++ has a drop-down menu called 'encoding'; notepad has encoding options in its save-as dialog; linux subsystem's `touch` command can be used rather than batch's `echo` command to create files via commandline.

Converting a file to utf-8: `Get-Content .\test.txt | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 test-utf8.txt` thanks to post by [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/a/1163765/69724).

### PowerShell Command:

`Set-Content <filename> -Encoding <Encoding>`

For example: `Set-Content my_file.txt -Encoding utf8`(*1).

*1. Please note: **case-sensitive**!